# segmentation fault compiler error in C

Tags: c, linked-list

```
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data)
{
 // Complete this method
   Node *temp, *temp1;
   temp1 = head;
   temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   temp->data = data;
   temp->next = NULL;
   while(temp1->next!=NULL){
       temp1 = temp1->next;
   }
   temp1->next = temp;
   return head;
}
```

I am trying to write simple code to insert at the end of the array. The method works for GCC compiler, but gives segmentation fault error when compiling using an online compiler on HackerRank. Does the program work differently for different compilers.

Comment: Segfault is a run-time error, not compiler. You need to provide [mcve].

Comment: Do not cast return value of malloc.

Comment: What if the list is empty, i.e. if `head` is NULL?

Comment: The first case when the linked list is empty, head will be NULL. So add a condition to assign temp to head if head is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment : The first case when the linked list is empty, head will be NULL. So add a condition to assign temp to head if head is null

```
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data)
{
  // Complete this method
   Node *temp, *temp1;
   temp1 = head;
   temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   temp->data = data;
   temp->next = NULL;
   if(head==NULL) head=temp; //ADDED THIS LINE
   else{
     while(temp1->next!=NULL){
        temp1 = temp1->next;
     }
   temp1->next = temp;
   }
  return head;
}
```

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Made changes :)